# How to call right way set Wallpaper intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, wallpapermanager

I'm working wallpaper application and having a problem with set wallpaper intent. I'm tried FileProvider, nothing changed.

My code showing this intent:
(1) https://i.ibb.co/RcW15qb/1.png

after select:
(2) https://i.ibb.co/nsQNvms/Screenshot-1568305811.png

but I want like this:
(3) https://i.ibb.co/F53p6sv/Screenshot-1568305398.png

```
fun setWallpaper (uri:Uri) {
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA) 
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*")
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*")
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"))}
```

I'm searched and tried smiliar set wallpaper intent example. Working but picture 1 and 2. I need intent like picture 3

Edit: I found but without scrolling and fixed options

```
 val intent = Intent("android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER")
```

(4) https://i.ibb.co/H4vqdGF/Screenshot-1568315850.png

Comment: Image 1 shows you're sharing the image to another app. That's when you lose control over what happens next. So what you see in image 2 and 3 are not android intents. They're different applications used to set walpapers that allow receiving "image/*" type. These applications can come with android or from the store. If you need more powerfull wallpaper setting you have to download more powerful app and then choose it from the list (if the app allows receiving images to set them as a wallpaper).

Comment: Yes, these and other wallpaper apps from market and set wallpaper like picture 3. But how ? I can't find it.

Comment: When I run your code I see also `Nova wallpaper` which is part of `Nova launcher` app (but that's probably more than you need). I also see `Wallpaper (Gallery)` (which is part of standard Gallery app that comes with Huawei phone). Both of them allow setting "scrollable" wallpaper.

Comment: Yes, I know. if click to "Other" in picture 3, open the menu in picture 1. I want to integrate my app. But I don't know.

Comment: Finally, I found. But without Scrolling and Fixed settings.

val intent = Intent("android.service.wallpaper.CROP_AND_SET_WALLPAPER")